Unable to hide/show bottom nav view on scroll (Fragment -> Activity)
Im trying to add hide/show behaviour for bottom nav view but its not working
im refering to this answer
according to that answer i have added the app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
but it didnt worked, probably becuase that the reyclerview that im having is in a fragment and the bottom nav is in the main activity, but im not sure
Here is activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e7e7e7"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goodbyetext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/calibriregular"
        android:text="Goodbye"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#36332c"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/appToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#e7e7e7"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="@font/calibriregular"
                android:text="That Button Again"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#36332c"
                android:textSize="25dp" />


            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/aboutPage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|end"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="#fffdf6"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <com.indiedev91.thatbuttonagain.DotsTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        layout="@layout/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />



    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_navigation_style"
            app:itemIconSize="30dp"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/buttonText"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

and here is the fragment buttons which contains the reyclerview
fragment_buttons.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e7e7e7"
    tools:context=".ButtonsFragment">




    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/btnRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        layout="@layout/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

and just for a note that the coordinator layout i used just above the bottom nav in main activity xml is to apply a border
also as this was not working i tried the programmatically , so in the fragment button java
ButtonsFragment.java
bottomNavigationView =  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        if (dy > 0 && bottomNavigationView.isShown()) {

           bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (dy < 0) {
            bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});

but as you can guess this dosent give the slide down and slide up animation style that i can get from the behaviour of HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior

Okay so i figured out that if i remove the CoordinatorLayout from above the bottomnavview in main activity it works perfectly
but then the issue was about the border applied to bottom nav , so for that i used layer-list
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Border -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/buttonBorder"/>
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!--Bottom Nav Corner Radius -->
    <item android:left="2.5dp" android:right="2.5dp" android:top="2.5dp" android:bottom="2.5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/buttonColor"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

and here is the bottomnavview after the modification
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/combined_shape"
        app:itemIconSize="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/buttonText"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

